# How to retrieve the used size of a Database?

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-express

What is the best way to retrieve the used size of a (sql) Database in c#?
I have access to the connection string of the database and assume I also have dbadmin access to the database.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.dataspaceusage.aspx) place suggests that I use Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll, however I would like to know if it is possible to do this using the Sql* namespaces in System.Data itself? (like SqlConnection, DbConnection, etc)

Comment: What exactly is 'the size of the database' ?  The file-size?

Comment: yes, I mean the .mdf and .ldf files.

Comment: Sorry, whats wrong with using Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll ? I am fan of Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll have developed so many DB tools using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sp_spaceused` returns allocated and unused space. ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx ), subtract the latter from the former to get the actual used space.

```
EXEC sp_spaceused
```

For sql server variants.

Just create a DbConnection and execute this sproc

[how to query sql server database size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136459/how-to-query-sql-server-database-size/2136567#2136567)

Comment: This again gives me only the total size allocated for the database initially which in my case is 3500 MB. However I am using only 12MB and the remaining is all free. I would like to know exactly how much I am using and how much is free. Any thoughts? Note that we can see this free space information by right clicking on a database in Sql Server management studio.

Comment: Updated to describe sp_spaceused better

Comment: ok; got it; It works now! reader["unallocated space"] gets the unallocated space.

Comment: I think the SP takes into account only the mdf file; Is there a way to do this for ldf files also?

Comment: Interesting.. I see that too.  Maybe a little research will show a way to get the index size and log file size too?

Comment: I am able to see only 2 files, one for data and one for log; Is the index file part of these? or is it stored elsewhere?

Answer (score 4):

For an attached database you can retrieve the filename from the connection. With that you can construct the .ldf filename as well and use System.IO.File to get the filesizes.

For 'normal' server-registered dbs I wouldn't know.

Comment: Once i construct the .mdf file name and use System.IO.File APIs to get the file size, I get the initial allocated size and not the currently used size.

Answer (score 4):

You could just query the SQL-Server to get that information:

```
USE <databasename>;
GO

/* get the database size, including the log file */
exec sp_spaceused;

/* get the size of the table */
exec sp_spaceused <tablename>;

/* the actual database file sizes */
SELECT * FROM sys.database_files;
```

Comment: SQL Server 2005 and up, I'd recommend using `SELECT * FROM sys.database_files` instead - the "old" `sysobjects` and `sysfiles` catalog views will be removed sooner or later....

Comment: @marc_s: thanks, updated the answer with your information. (I Wanted to add this comment a few hours ago after the actual update, but then our company suffered from connection problems.. so here we go now)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are any direct ways to do that through the Sql.* namespaces, but you could use the ADO.NET framework to run the [sp_spaceused (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx) stored procedure.

See this SO question: [how to query sql server database size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136459/how-to-query-sql-server-database-size)